# Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl'

Tags: android, google-play-services

My project specifies `support-v4-26.1.0` as one of its dependencies, which in turn uses

```
android.library.reference.1=../support-compat-26.1.0
android.library.reference.2=../support-media-compat-26.1.0
android.library.reference.3=../support-core-ui-26.1.0
android.library.reference.4=../support-core-utils-26.1.0
android.library.reference.5=../support-fragment-26.1.0
```

On Android sdk 10, this crash occurs:

```
Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:46)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:63)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:871)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:100)
```

How can this be fixed?

**Edit**: I decompiled my apk and see that `FragmentManagerImpl` exists in `android.support.v4.app` package, so it's not a `ProGuard` issue.

Comment: update to `27.1.1` ...or check the ProGuard configuration, in case it's an obfuscated release build.

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentManagerImpl` implements `Factory2`, which requires API 11. This should be the reason for the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception: at moment I don't know how to fix this. I tried extending that class but it isn't public.

Anyway I'll continue looking for a solution even if API 10 isn't supported at the moment because I want to keep my app's compatibility high.

English mistakes? I'm an Italian teenager, sorry :-)